# How to use If statement within for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to solve the following problem: 
If there are countries containing 'land', print it as array. If there is no country containing the word 'land', print 'All these are countries without land'. 
The problem is that when I put if-else statements within the loop it prints all steps in iteration which I do not need. However, outside the loop, I can print only one statement. So where I should put the message when the condition fails? Please help, it seems simple but I couldn't solve it.

```
for(let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
    if(countries[i].includes('land'))
    arr.push(countries[i])
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you know that if there was atleast one country containing word `land` then `arr` will not have length of **zero**

you can use this length to verify if there was no country found

```js
for(let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
    if(countries[i].includes('land'))
    arr.push(countries[i])
}
if(arr.length > 0 )
  console.log(arr);
else
  console.log('All these are countries without land')
```

Comment: Thank You so much!

Comment: keep practicing